# How to differentiate between PNP powersehell command for sharepoint online versus sharepoint 2013

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server, pnp-powershell, pnp

How to differentiate between PNP powershell command for sharepoint online versus sharepoint 2013? I have both installed
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its depend which module imported, we can have all pnppowershell versions in side by side.  When you run powershell, its depend on which module you imported n which environment you targeted.

One thing, almost all command are in pnp online moduule so their are chances that if you imported pnponline module then many modern stuff command will not work.

Here is really good example for it.

https://www.google.com/amp/s/thechriskent.com/2018/02/14/using-sharepoint-pnp-powershell-modules-side-by-side-2013-2016-online/amp/

https://www.google.com/amp/s/www.erwinmcm.com/running-the-various-versions-of-pnp-powershell-side-by-side/amp/